# Will the distances to each other corner from any corner of a regular polygon be the same?

Tags: geometry

I mean, this is somehow obvious, but tangled my head.

For clarification, I mean,

1. The case for a regular triangle, the distances from all other
   corners from any corner is `d` and `d` **and same for all corners.**
2. The case for a square(regular rectangle) the distances from all
   other corners from any corner is `d` `d` and `d*sqrt(2)` **and same
   for all corners.**

.

.

.

Is this something always be satisfied?

note: I am using word *regular* to state that the all of the edge lengths are equal. I don't know if this is a suitable word in English though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular polygon is a polygon that is both equilateral (all sides have the same length) *and* equiangular (all angles have the same size). With this definition, the set of distances from one corner of a regular polygon to all the other corners is the same regardless of which corner you measure from. This is a consequence of the symmetry of each regular polygon.

As joriki has pointed out in their answer, the equiangular condition is necessary, as this property is not always true for a polygon that is only equilateral.

Answer (score 2):

No, the term “regular” is usually reserved for polygons in which all edge lengths and all angles are equal. In that case the set of distances is obviously the  same for each vertex by symmetry.

The way you’re using the term, the sets of distances need not be the same. For instance, consider a [rhombus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombus), which has four edges of equal lengths, but two corners are closer to each other than the other two corners are.

Comment: oh, yes, I should've also thought about angles. Thank you, great answer. I accepted the other one just because you look like having lots of reputation already :)